# Convert object to mapped Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object

Is there a way to improve this code to convert object to mapped array?

I have came up with this solution, is there a better approach and cleaner?

```
let productItems =  {
    'Item1': { 
        quantity: 4, 
        name: 4,
        price: 123
    },
    'Item2': { 
        quantity: 1, 
        name: 3,
        price: 144
    },
    'Item3': { 
        quantity: 2, 
        name: 2,
        price: 343
    }
}

let items = [];

for (const item in productItems) {
    const formatItem = {
        "Qty": productItems[item].quantity,
        "Cost": productItems[item].price
    }

    items.push(formatItem);
}
```

Output:

```
[ { Qty: 4, Cost: 123 },
  { Qty: 1, Cost: 144 },
  { Qty: 2, Cost: 343 } ]
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)

> The `Object.values()` method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property values, in the same order as that provided by a `for...in` loop (the difference being that a for-in loop enumerates properties in the prototype chain as well).

and [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

> The `map()` method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

```js
let productItems =  {
    'Item1': { 
        quantity: 4, 
        name: 4,
        price: 123
    },
    'Item2': { 
        quantity: 1, 
        name: 3,
        price: 144
    },
    'Item3': { 
        quantity: 2, 
        name: 2,
        price: 343
    }
}

let items = Object.values(productItems).map(i => ({Qty: i.quantity, Cost: i.price}));
console.log(items);
```

Answer (score 1):

Object.values will work fine. in case you want to access the keys and values both you can use Object.entries with map

```
Object.entries({
'Item1': { 
    quantity: 4, 
    name: 4,
    price: 123
},
'Item2': { 
    quantity: 1, 
    name: 3,
    price: 144
},
'Item3': { 
    quantity: 2, 
    name: 2,
    price: 343
}}).map(([key, {quantity, price}]) => ({Qty: quantity, Cost: price}))
```

Comment: `Object.entries(obj)` returns an array of arrays. The example you've provided will not work as expected. It's easy to fix with array destructuring though: `[key, item] => (...)`

Comment: This is still wrong. You should read the documentation for `Object.entries()` and test out your code before posting it.

Comment: I am extremely sorry, this is embarrassing. I have updated the answer